# What iPad game is this using joysticks on the screen?

Tags: game-identification

I just found an image of an old game for iPad! Can anyone identify what game it is? Here is a picture of it.

[image: still image of the game being played]

Comment: Don't forget to a accept an answer if it answered your issue

Answer (score 22):

By reverse Google imaging your picture, I came across [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CC-5VpZGjgo&ebc=ANyPxKqVXWBMeZu4Ahk7I0oMWKNYGYvIrxXAcbxJW3XTg1l5yURvB7qEAt5zbg0C0P_O2RxH3C-hr0wuZGIcMu6AvoiTn1zFWg) embedded in [this page for the joysticks](http://www.thinkgeek.com/product/e75a/), which includes the same game as your image. Fortunately, a list of all games included in the video is provided and, after viewing the video, the listed games appear to be arranged in order of their appearances in the video.

The game you're looking for is called [**iDracula**](http://imoregames.com/idracula.htm).